# System.DllNotFoundException: @rpath/libSkiaSharp.framework/libSkiaSharp assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am getting below exception while using Microcharts.Forms(0.9.5.9) package in Xamarin forms, I am getting this exception on ios side only. I am currently using visual studio for mac(8.7.8-build 4). I am checking this in ios simulator iphone 11 pro with ios 14.0.

```
System.DllNotFoundException: @rpath/libSkiaSharp.framework/libSkiaSharp assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) SkiaSharp.SkiaApi.sk_color_premultiply(uint)
  at SkiaSharp.SKPMColor.PreMultiply (SkiaSharp.SKColor color) [0x00006] in <659007ac60e94125a4c9f512b9669a79>:0
  at SkiaSharp.Views.iOS.Extensions+<>c.<.cctor>b__15_0 () [0x00000] in <cae2c036472b46c8bc8acfecce5cdb6a>:0
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed package `SkiaSharp (2.80.2)` in my .netstandard(Shared) project and issue get solved.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).